# how can i make the button width: 100% when it's below text-area

Tags: html, css

I have tried using grid with auto-fit but i can't get it to work is there a way i can do this without javascript? (or use JS (didn't learn js yet but for future reference)) preferably without JS

```css
.inputgroup1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#submit {
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#commentbox {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 24px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputgroup inputgroup1">
      <textarea id="commentbox" class="commentbox" name="comment" placeholder="comment me"></textarea> <button type="submit" id="submit" form="survey-form" value="submit">Submit!</button>
      </div>
```

Comment: Try giving the button the `flex: auto;` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i make the button width: 100% when it's below text-area

As you have set `inputgroup1` as `flex` you can use `flex:1` on child elements to take up entire space.

```css
.inputgroup1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#submit {
/*   width: auto; */
/*   display: block; */
  flex: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#commentbox {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 24px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputgroup inputgroup1">
      <textarea id="commentbox" class="commentbox" name="comment" placeholder="comment me"></textarea> 
      <button type="submit" id="submit" form="survey-form" value="submit">Submit!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that the button doesn't have a specified width.
In essence you don't even need to utilize flex or grid for this specific problem.
You could essentially have normal block elements with a defined width. If the container takes up 100% of the width, the other elements will be pushed below it.

With that said, I have chosen to keep your current flex approach.

You could do it like this:

```css
.inputgroup {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inputgroup .commentbox {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 24px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button#submit {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputgroup inputgroup1">
      <textarea id="commentbox" class="commentbox" name="comment" placeholder="comment me" rows="6"></textarea> <button type="submit" id="submit" form="survey-form" value="submit">Submit!</button>
      </div>
```